# WordPress Retrieve Post by Title

Tags: posts

The following code works brilliantly for retrieving certain pages, but I can't get it to retrieve POSTS by name. I'd like exactly the same code, but to retrieve posts rather than pages. Any help appreciated.

```
<?php
    function get_my_content($page) {
        $my_id = $page;
        $post_id = get_post($my_id, ARRAY_A);
        $content = $post_id['post_content'];

        return $content;
    }
?>    

<div id='test'>
    <?php 
        $page = get_page_by_title('testpage');
        echo get_my_content($page);
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Where and how is "get_my_content" defined?

Comment: I have no idea I'm afraid. I'm new to php, someone else gave me that piece of code, all I know is that the code above is all that's required to pull in multiple pages to different divs. But for some reason it only works with pages, not posts.

Comment: I'm sorry my bad, the definition is in your example. However this should return posts already, if you use a posts id instead of a pages. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536682/get-wordpress-post-id-from-post-title

Comment: I think it's something to do with get_page_by_title, because by default it's page, however there are no examples of how to set it to 'post' http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title

Comment: Yes I saw that question, I'd rather just adapt my code though. Think I just need to tweak the $page = get_page_by_title bit to set it to post type.

Comment: That's step one, step two is to adjust how the function handles the argument, and for that you could tap from the suggested answer. I'll have a look in a minute.

Comment: Can anyone find an example of how to set the $post_type parameter to 'post'? It's ridiculous that they don't give all the parameter examples here codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title get_page_by_title( $page_title, $output, $post_type );

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3772/discussion-between-sparrohawx-and-jasper-kennis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per docs you only need to specify different post type to make it work:

```
$page = get_page_by_title('testpage', OBJECT, 'post');
```

Comment: Great, that worked! I knew it was something simple. Thanks v much Rarst

Answer (score 0):

Using that earlier question I was referring to, you could do something like this:

```
<?php
  function get_my_content($page_title) {
    global $wpdb;
    $post = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = %s AND post_type='post'", $page_title ));
    if ( $post )
      $post_id = get_post($my_id, ARRAY_A);
      return $post_id['post_content'];

    return null;
  }
?>

<div id='test'>
    <?php 
        $page = get_page_by_title('testpost');
        echo get_my_content($page);
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jasper, I tried this but it didn't work. Think it's also missing a closing } and $page should be $post, but still didn't work.

Comment: A closing bracket was missing indeed, I've edited that. The name of the variable doesn't matter, and it's good this way I believe, although it's hard coding without seeing the results. Are you sure you're searching for an existing title? Because if the title doesn't exist, nothing is returned, obviously.

Comment: Hi Jasper, tried again but no result unfortunately. The post definitely exists.

Answer (score 0):

Does this post over on Wordpress.org help you? http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-posts-based-on-page-title

Comment: Thanks Chrs, interesting information but it didn't really help me fetch a post by title, like the above code does with pages.